# NRF24L01+ (TMRH20 library): Receiver gets blank data

Tags: serial, arduino-nano, nrf24l01+

I am working on sample Arduino project for communication over NRF24L01+ (TMRH20 library), everything is working fine with my example except one issue my Receiver gets message but that message is blank. Now i am not sure how do i debug as per serial monitor data is getting transmitted, as per receiver serial monitor it receives data but its blank.

Transmitter code -

```cpp
// SimpleTx - the master or the transmitter

#include <SPI.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <RF24.h>


#define CE_PIN   9
#define CSN_PIN 10

const byte slaveAddress[5] = {'R','x','A','A','A'};


RF24 radio(CE_PIN, CSN_PIN); // Create a Radio

char dataToSend[12] = "Msg AKSHAY";
//int dataToSend = 1;
char txNum = '0';


unsigned long currentMillis;
unsigned long prevMillis;
unsigned long txIntervalMillis = 1000; // send once per second


void setup() {

    Serial.begin(9600);

    Serial.println("SimpleTx Starting");

    radio.begin();
    radio.setDataRate( RF24_250KBPS );
    radio.setRetries(3,5); // delay, count
    radio.openWritingPipe(slaveAddress);
}

//====================

void loop() {
    currentMillis = millis();
    if (currentMillis - prevMillis >= txIntervalMillis) {
        send();
        prevMillis = millis();
    }
}

//====================

void send() {

    bool rslt;
    rslt = radio.write( &dataToSend, sizeof(dataToSend) );
        // Always use sizeof() as it gives the size as the number of bytes.
        // For example if dataToSend was an int sizeof() would correctly return 2

    Serial.print("Data Sent ");
    Serial.print(dataToSend);
    if (rslt) {
        Serial.println("  Acknowledge received");
        updateMessage();
    }
    else {
        Serial.println("  Tx failed");
    }
}

//================

void updateMessage() {
        // so you can see that new data is being sent
    txNum += 1;
    if (txNum > '9') {
        txNum = '0';
    }
    dataToSend[10] = txNum;
}
```

Receiver code -

```cpp
// SimpleRx - the slave or the receiver

#include <SPI.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <RF24.h>

#define CE_PIN   9
#define CSN_PIN 10

const byte thisSlaveAddress[5] = {'R','x','A','A','A'};

RF24 radio(CE_PIN, CSN_PIN);

char dataReceived[10]; // this must match dataToSend in the TX
bool newData = false;

//===========

void setup() {

    Serial.begin(9600);

    Serial.println("SimpleRx Starting");
    radio.begin();
    radio.setDataRate( RF24_250KBPS );
    radio.openReadingPipe(1, thisSlaveAddress);
    radio.startListening();
}

//=============

void loop() {
    getData();
    showData();
}

//==============

void getData() {
  if ( radio.available() ) {

       radio.read( &dataReceived, sizeof(dataReceived) );
      Serial.println(dataReceived);
       newData = true;
   } else {
       Serial.println("No radio available");
   }
   delay(100);
}

void showData() {
    if (newData == true) {
        Serial.print("Data received ");
        Serial.println(dataReceived);
        newData = false;
    }
}
```

Below is the output TX1 (Transmitter ) and RX1 is Receiver. You can see that Transmitter even gets acknowledgment also..

[image]

Both of my devices are arduino nano and below is wiring diagram between arduino and nrf24l01.
[image]

I also saw few post where people suggested using 100uf capacitor in NRF24L01 (GND & VCC), this helped me with accuracy in connection but data is still missing.

Comment: Had you tried the `for loop` while printing your data on the serial as you are receiving data in the form of char array.

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't help.

Comment: Can you please upload the unmodified PingPair example and see if that works? It's really hard to see the real cause if it might be just your code.

Answer (score 3):

I have tested your code. There appears to be defective clones of the nRF24L01 around that exhibit an issue I show in post [nRF24L01 continuously reading closed pipe](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/85874/nrf24l01-continuously-reading-closed-pipe)
You can work around this issue by changing your code as follows (although your process still has to read all those nulls):

```
void getData() {
  uint8_t pipeNum;
  if ( radio.available(&pipeNum) ) {

       radio.read( &dataReceived, sizeof(dataReceived) );
      //Serial.println(dataReceived);
      if (pipeNum < 2) {
       newData = true;
      }
   } else {
       Serial.println("No radio available");
   }
   // delay(100);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

A couple of clarifications first

1. At the time instant 22:38, the receiver isn't detecting any available radio devices but at the transmitter side, an acknowledge is received. How is that possible? How is your tx getting an ack without the rx getting connected.
2. I have not seen slave adresses being set as - 
   `const byte slaveAddress[5] = {'R','x','A','A','A'};`
    For the record, **NRF24L01 adresses are 5 bytes long** by default and not 1 byte long as you have defined. While defining the pipe addresses, the first 4 bytes of the adresses should be same among all the pipe addresses. Only the last byte should be unique.
    Pipe addresses can be `0xF0F0F0F0A1, 0XF0F0F0F0B1, 0XF0F0F0F0C1, 0XF0F0F0F0D1, 0XF0F0F0F0E1` 
   Try setting the pipe addresses as 
   `uint_64t address[5] = {0xF0F0F0F0A1LL, 0XF0F0F0F0B1LL, 0XF0F0F0F0C1LL, 0XF0F0F0F0D1LL, 0XF0F0F0F0E1LL};`
   Do the same declaration at the receiver end too. And btw, you can specify any byte you want in the last byte of the address. Here I have defined the last bytes as `A1`, `B1`, `C1`, `D1`, `E1`.
3. To make sure that communication is successful, set some custom ack byte and compare it with the received ack. If both match, you can be sure that the rx did get the data. Sometimes, the NRF24L01 can pickup garbage values from stray signals present around and it can consider it as data sent by the receiver. So to avoid false triggering, its better to make a fool-proof ACK mechanism.

Comment: Your second point makes no sense at all. You are trying to stuff five-byte-wide values into one byte, which is pointless. In fact, the original intent of the OP with his `const byte slaveAddress[5] = {'R','x','A','A','A'};` apparently is an attempt to create a 5-byte address. Exactly as you said it should be. It is a *single* slave address, not five of them.

Comment: Sorry! It should be uint_64t. Thanks for pointing it out AnT

Comment: (Firstly, it's `uint64_t`, not `uint_64t`.) But that will declare 5 separate addresses. How is that relevant to the OP's question? Why 5? He does not need five separate addresses, he just needs one.

Comment: Also, this is an example from RF24 header file itself: `uint8_t address[] = { 0xCC,0xCE,0xCC,0xCE,0xCC }; radio.openWritingPipe(address);`.  (https://github.com/nRF24/RF24/blob/master/RF24.h#L246) As you can see, this is the same thing as in the OP's code. There's nothing wrong with it.