# NRF24L01+ Getting Started Acknowledge Failed

Tags: arduino-uno, nrf24l01+

I have followed numerous guides and tutorials for getting the NRF24L01+ modules working with an Arduino Uno. I have swapped to a genuine Arduino and tried 4 different NRF modules. All without luck.

I am trying to get the most basic example from [Simple nRF24L01+ 2.4GHz transceiver demo](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=421081.0) to work.

Hardware Connections:
[image: Hardware Connections]

Simple TX Test Code:

```
// SimpleTx - the master or the transmitter

#include <SPI.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <RF24.h>


#define CE_PIN   9
#define CSN_PIN 10

const byte slaveAddress[5] = {'R','x','A','A','A'};



RF24 radio(CE_PIN, CSN_PIN); // Create a Radio

char dataToSend[10] = "Message 0";
char txNum = '0';


unsigned long currentMillis;
unsigned long prevMillis;
unsigned long txIntervalMillis = 1000; // send once per second


void setup() {

    Serial.begin(9600);

    Serial.println("SimpleTx Starting");

    radio.begin();
    radio.setDataRate( RF24_250KBPS );
    radio.setRetries(3,5); // delay, count
    radio.openWritingPipe(slaveAddress);
}

//====================

void loop() {
    currentMillis = millis();
    if (currentMillis - prevMillis >= txIntervalMillis) {
        send();
        prevMillis = millis();
    }
}

//====================

void send() {

    bool rslt;
    radio.stopListening();
    rslt = radio.write( &dataToSend, sizeof(dataToSend) );
        // Always use sizeof() as it gives the size as the number of bytes.
        // For example if dataToSend was an int sizeof() would correctly return 2

    Serial.print("Data Sent ");
    Serial.print(dataToSend);

    if (rslt) {
        Serial.println("  Acknowledge received");
        updateMessage();
    }
    else {
        Serial.println("  Tx failed");
    }
}

//================

void updateMessage() {
        // so you can see that new data is being sent
    txNum += 1;
    if (txNum > '9') {
        txNum = '0';
    }
    dataToSend[8] = txNum;
}
```

Serial monitor:

[image]

Using `radio.printDetails( );` returns:

[image]

Please let me know what I'm missing.

Comment: Can you please upload the unmodified PingPair example and see if that works?

Comment: Where is the code for the receiving side? If there is no receiver, the sender won't get an ACK packet back, and you get the `TX failed` error message.

Comment: What is this: `uint8_t slaveAddress[5] = {0xF0F0F0F0A1LL, 0XF0F0F0F0B1LL, 0XF0F0F0F0C1LL, 0XF0F0F0F0D1LL, 0XF0F0F0F0E1LL};`? How do you expect such large values to fit into `uint8_t`??? The compiler will interpret this as `uint8_t slaveAddress[5] = {0xA1, 0xB1, 0xC1, 0xD1, 0xE1};`. Is this what you wanted? I'd guess not. Also, take a look here https://github.com/nRF24/RF24/blob/master/RF24.h#L246 how the address is supposed to be formed.

Comment: @AnT I was trying the same as 1 of the answers here: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/65249/nrf24l01-tmrh20-library-receiver-gets-blank-data before you commented there as well. Thank you, have updated the question and code.

Comment: Thank you all so much. Not sure why I was expecting the radio.write function to return True without a receiving end. It's working.

Comment: How did you get `RF_CH=0x76`?  That's not the default radio channel on power up, so are you not showing the complete version of the code?

Answer (score 1):

The Arduinos 3V3 does not privide enough current. To eliminate this as a source of your problem you can use a ceramic capacitor of 100µF across VCC and GND pins of the nRF24L01+ module or buy a [5V to 3V3 step down converter specially made for nRF24L01](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/New-Socket-Adapter-plate-Board-for-8Pin-NRF24L01-Wireless-Transceive-module-51/32825890092.html).